# EOL/Obsolete Software: Apache Log4j 1.X Detected

Tags: pyspark, livy

currently we are having Apache Log4j 1.X on one of our docker image which is reported as EOL and needs to update to Apache Log4j 2.X version but we are unable to find that package to upgrade it to Log4j 1.X.

reported package log4j-1.2.16.jar needed package log4j-2.x.x.jar

reported path= /home/livy/server/target/jars/log4j-1.2.16.jar

we want to replace package but not able to find that package

we have tried to search file in the server

how to get that file or it is not released from vendor side